# LLDB 3.9.0 Crashing (CLion)

Tags: c++11, lldb, clion, llvm-clang

[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B89OaFL73_sWWmJOaURWZmFxcjA/view?usp=sharing) is a link to a C++ (CLion) project. I've distilled/simplified the issue down as much as I could.

The problem is that when debugging, LLDB (version 3.9.0) crashes.

**Steps to reproduce crash:**

1. Open project with CLion 2017.1 (use built in LLDB for debug)
2. Compile the Project
3. Place breakpoint in main.cpp line 14
4. Run in debug mode.
5. Once you're at line 14 breakpoint, then output the variable "an_integer" via the "print an_integer" command.
6. Crash

The Error/Crash Report:

> Assertion failed: (D->getCachedLinkage() == LV.getLinkage()), function
>   getLVForDecl, file
>   /Applications/buildAgent/work/92515a49514b3993/lldb/llvm/tools/clang/lib/AST/Decl.cpp,
>   line 1360.

Note that this crash occurs with LLDB v3.9.0 on Mac v10.12.4. But it does not occur with LLDB 3.7.0 on Mac 10.12.4.

***Ultimately, I'm wanting to know if I'm doing something dumb in my project code? If not, is this a bug with CLion or LLDB? Is there somewhere that I should post this to help get the bug (if it is that) resolved?***

Comment: I observed a crash, when stepping into heavy meta-programming templates. In my case Boost Meta-Statemachines. If I just skip stepping into MSM, everything works find.

Comment: Hey! ended up finding a fix?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like your bug.  For some reason lldb is having trouble ingesting the type information produced by the compiler.

I don't have clion so I can't try that, but if I just build your test project, either with a PCH or without, using clang from Xcode 8.3 I don't see this crash.  Best thing to do is to build this project with CLion, then make a dSYM (if CLion doesn't do this for you.)  You do that by running:

```
 > dsymutil TestingLLDBBreaking
```

Check that you can reproduce the crash with the dSYM, and if so then file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com with the executable and the .dSYM.

Comment: dsymutil produces no errors. Furthermore, if I use lldb-370.0.40 (via command line) after compiling with CLion, I also get no error. It is something to do with CLion in conjunction with lldb 3.9.0 I believe. I'll post over at their issue tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP)

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem for a while. 
just before almost formatting my mac I've re-cloned the project to a different directory and ran it from there. No issues.  (i'm sure its a mac-os thing).
Good luck :)